# Text Compression in Erlang

Tags: database, memory-management, erlang, cryptography, compression

Is there a text compression library for Erlang?  When working with very long strings, it may be advantageous to compress the character data. Has anyone compressed text or thought of a way to do it in Erlang?

I was thinking of using the `zip` module, but instead of working with files, I work in-memory like this:

```
compress(LargeText)->
    Binary = list_to_binary(LargeText),
    {ok,{_,Zipped}} = zip:zip("ZipName",[{"Name",Binary}],[memory]),
    Zipped.
```

Then I would `unzip` the text back into memory when I need it. Like this:

```
{ok,[{"Name",Binary}]} = zip:unzip(Zipped,[memory]).
```

My Erlang application is supposed to be part of a middle tier in which large text may have to pass through to, and out of a storage system. The storage system is intended on storing large text. To optimize the storage, there is need to compress it before sending it. Assume that the text value is like a `CLOB` data type in Oracle Database. I am thinking that if I combine the zipping and the `erlang:garbage_collect/0`, i can pull it off.

Or if it's not possible in Erlang, perhaps it is possible using a `system call` via `os:cmd({Some UNIX script})` and then I would grab the output in Erlang? If there's a better way, please show it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [zlib module for Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/zlib.html), which supports in-memory compression and decompression.

Comment: i had seen this already. But probably thought it may not differ so much from the `zip` module

Comment: It differs a great deal.  Please read the documentation.  This _is_ the droid you're looking for.  It compresses and decompresses compact streams that do not use the zip format and do not carry information about file names, etc.  You can also read the zlib manual (http://zlib.net/manual.html) and examples of the use of zlib (http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using [snappy](https://github.com/fdmanana/snappy-erlang-nif) compression which is a lot faster than zip especially for decompression.

**Edit**:
Nowadays I am using [LZ4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/) a lot and I am very happy with it. It has a nice and readable code, simple format, well maintained and is even faster than Snappy.